# NFC Readers with Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, nfc

Not sure if this is a Stack Overflow question (if anyone knows a more apropiate section of StackExchange I'll be happy) but all questions on NFC Readers seamed to be here so, here I go:

I want to use NFC-Tags for a project and need a reader. While more and more phones are capable of reading such tags, any older phone is not. These phones do however usually have Bluetooth. So what I am looking for is a NFC Reader that can connect to a phone via Bluetooth.

I thought this would be a common device but to my surprise I did not find much. Readers usually connect via usb (as [these](http://nfctags.tagstand.com/#nfc-reader-writers) do). There is at least one device that does use Bluetooth, the [Blueberry UHF](http://www.tertiumtechnology.com/blueberry_uhf.php), but I could not find any retailer that sells it.

So, my question would be this: Is there a reason that there are almost no such devices or am I just looking at the wrong places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of device you refer to is available here: https://serialio.com//store/index.php?cPath=89&osCsid=nep7av4i0431r39eqdl23oh2i7.

The reason you struggle to find a Bluetooth enabled device is because the peripheral market for NFC/RFID readers are targeted at the desktop embedded market where USB/RS232 cable options are cheaper/easier/stable offerings people are familiar with. The driver stack provided with a cabled device can also do a lot of the hard work in dealing with the incoming data. 
There are however a few companies on the market producing RS232 to Bluetooth bridges which means you can try and port peripherals across to this using Bluetooth. Although you'll be able to pair the devices, you'll then need to write the software that can interrupt in the incoming payload over the Bluetooth serial port connection so it'll be a lot more work to get a platform like this up and running - especially with older devices. However it is possible if required.

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late answering this questions, but maybe my response will help others who are searching for the same thing. What you are looking for is available from Serialio. There are multiple Bluetooth NFC readers available. The BlueBerry is re-branded with the Scanfob brand.

Here is a link to the updated Scanfob NFC page (the above link posted earlier no longer works): https://serialio.com/products/rfid/readerwriters/scanfob%C2%AE-nfc-bb2

There are multiple apps available that interface with the readers. This really depends on what you want to do with data from your reads. 
Heres' an example of attendance managment solution using an NFC reader on Android:
https://serialio.com/products/mobile/software/MobileGrid/Android/use/TimeTrack/MG_TimeTrack_Android.php

There's a lot more. I just don't have the reputation to add more links yet.

Comment: Your response is useful, but it is helpful if you add code from the pages cited. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer - 'Provide context for links'

Answer (score 1):

What possible problem would a NFC reader that connects to a phone via bluetooth solve? The phone is not going to know anything about NFC, it does not have the required software or stack.

Sure, you could write that software (possibly) but to what end? The unit you linked to is what you are after, sure, but it's for a very specialised purpose (i.e. you have to write the s/w at the other end).

It's likely to be cheaper (in time and money) to just buy a phone that supports NFC rather then trying to upgrade a unit that does not.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of such RFID-tags is utterly wrong but most of them offer little more then an ID and some other info that can be coded as a string when read. This data could easily be transmitted via bluetooth and be used by an app connected to the reader. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Not at all. But what is the target market for that device? It exists, you've linked to it but it's not for consumer use. So I suppose my question to you in return is "why not just buy a NFC supporting phone and read the tags directly instead of involving bluetooth"? The answer to that I suspect is the same as the answer to your original question ;)

Comment: I could think of a bunch of uses, for example in board games with digital enhancements (using the readers as figures and tags in boards or cards), in home automation (placing tags in homes and using the placement of such readers to provide information on the inhabitants), art or music (as a controller for virtual instruments using NFC), shoping (the usual digital wallet) and all this without having to use the phone which has multiple purposes and can not always serve the function of Reader but can be the gateway for the reader when otherwise used (and can remain in the pocket).

Comment: And all those things are happening right now, or will be shortly. But when/if they do the readers will be integrated into the devices/games themselves. The point is that you can go ahead and do your project right now when you obtain such a device but only you will be able to use it. Consumers will not want yet another device in their pocket that just duplicates something that their phone can already do. So the reason there is no such device is because nobody wants to buy it nor any compelling reason to buy it.

Comment: Well I cant argue the last point, apparently there is no marked (yet). I'll probably have to build one if I want to play with it... thankfully arduino seems to offer all the needed components.

Comment: Consider posting your own answer to your question for others, should you solve it.

Comment: I am looking for a small NFC reader that can talk bluetooth with my sons mobile phone from his continous glucose meter. Today the only viable solution is hacksy at best, with buying an Sony Smartwatch 3 and put it on top of the glucose meter (that is staying on my sons arm for 2 weeks) and let the clock talk to the phone and/or the cloud. This way he can get automatic scans without actually holding a phone against the CGM. That is the problem making me end up in this thread. I think it is a good use.